# How to use pos_tag in text classfication

Tags: python, nlp

I`m working to get a text classfication demo.I use scapy of python to make pos_tag for all sentence,but I dont know how to use these pos_tag in the demo, I just know it can be one of
features but I can not get it out.
Could you please help,thanks for all.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/74w0L.png)

Comment: Please provide example code in the text of your question, appropriately formatted https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question - include sample data in a similar way. What have you tried yourself? What problem did you run into? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.